# WebAPI Validation DataAnnotation creates runtime exception [HttpStatusCode 500]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I can't seems to find anything related to this issue on Google.
Please help !!

**SCENARIO:**
Mainly I have a WebAPI server with a controller method that expects a simple type as parameter.
That API looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Foo([FromBody] LoginModel form)
{
     // ...some code
     return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

and the LoginType class looks like this:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please have a Email address format")]
    public string Email;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Password must be between 6 and 20 characters")]
    public string Password;
}
```

Problem occurs when the Client tries to run the API method. I pass a json that looks like this
{ "Email" : "xxx@xxx.com" , "Password" : "oooooo" }

....I get the following exception

**EXCEPTION MESSAGE:**
"Field 'Email' on type 'XXXX.Models.Login' is attributed with one or more validation attributes. Validation attributes on fields are not supported. Consider using a public property for validation instead.

The same happens when I ran the api call from Fiddler !!

**NOTE:**
If I remove the various Attributes like [Required], it works smoothly. The client call never gets to the method when the Attributes are in place.

Help is truly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it says:

> Validation attributes on fields are not supported. Consider using a public property for validation instead.

So use properties;

```
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Easy one to miss, sometimes just takes another set of eyes!